# Sending message to two clients behind one public IP

Tags: firewall, port

So recently I have been developing a simple UDP server and client application (using C# with .NET), however I seem to have hit a dead end and am in need of advice.

The current situation is that the client is listening to port xx and the server is listening on a different port called x. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkUMk.png).

The public IP of the server is known by the client and port x is forwarded so that the server is able to receive messages from clients sending messages via port x.

As apart of any message sent by the client, the public IP of the client is sent to the server, so that the server may send a response back to that client.

My current testing has shown that this works reasonably well, until, there are two clients behind one public IP.

This causes a problem because packets of data sent by the server either arrive at the wrong computer or don't ever get received (I think the router just discards them because it can't figure out which one to send it to).

So what advice/methods can you give me to fix this issue?

Best Regards,
Ashley.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

Comment: If possible, use IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret your question is that you have a mostly working solution for IPv4, but it breaks down in certain corner cases involving NAT. What you can expect to happen in the future is that your IPv4 solution will face more and more corner cases which will get harder and harder to solve. For example you probably never tested your solution through NAT444, NAT64, NAT464-XLAT, or DSLITE and you can expect to see users on such configurations.

**My recommendation is to implement IPv6 support before you even start working on the corner cases of supporting IPv4.**

Once you have IPv6 support some of the corner cases with IPv4 will no longer be of any importance. For example you will never need to worry about communication between a client using NAT64 and another client using NAT464-XLAT.

Communication between two clients behind NAT can sometimes be made to work using UDP hole punching. But it can only work if at least one of the two NAT devices work in a predictable way. If both NAT devices are assigning port numbers in an unpredictable way it can be entirely impossible to achieve direct communication between the two devices.

I would build support for the following methods of connectivity:

- Direct IPv6 to IPv6 connectivity (with the connection initiated simultaneously from both ends, if required by the firewall).
- Direct IPv4 to IPv4 connectivity (with the connection initiated simultaneously from both ends, if required by the firewall).
- Connection established from peer behind NAT44/NAT444/NAT464 towards peer on a public IPv4 address. (As long as one peer has a public IPv4 address, it doesn't matter which of those three kinds of NAT the other peer is behind).
- Connection established from peer behind NAT64 towards peer on a public IPv4 address. (That requires you to create a DNS record for the peer on a public IPv4 address that the IPv6-only peer can resolve through DNS64).
- Indirect connection through a dual stack server hosted by you for those clients which cannot use any of the above. (It is only fair that you charge a higher price from users without a native IPv6 address to pay your costs for those servers.)

The above may sound a bit complicated. But it is not nearly as complicated as addressing every single corner case of IPv4 NAT behavior. (Had IPv6 been deployed to the majority of users before people started resorting to NAT, the above list of different methods of connectivity would have been a lot shorter.)

Answer (score 0):

When sending the packets, you want the client to use a source UDP port of A to send to destination port B on the server.
Then when the server responds, get it to use the source UDP port B to send to the destination port A on the client.

You should have a NAT fw/router between the server and the client. The NAT fw/router should have the public IP, and the server should have a public IP, but the clients have LAN ip addresses. When each client sends to the server, they shouldn't need to include their public IP. The NAT fw/router will change the source IP address for the outgoing packets so that it appears to come from the NAT fw/router public IP. Then, when the server sends back, as long as it does so in response to a client, and in a reasonable time, the NAT fw/router will know which client to send the response back to. This is done using connection tracking and stateful packet inspection.

```
   port B
   SERVER
 public ip1
      |
      |
  public ip2
  NATROUTER 
     / \
CLIENT1  CLIENT2
lan ip1   lan ip2
     port A
```

Sorry about the bad diagram!